# phonegap build whitelisting not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, phonegap-build

When using phonegap build, whitelisting doesn't seem to be working. When I run the application from a browser, all the ajax calls are successfull and the application works. I have the following config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
id="com.company.Demo" version="1.0.0">
<name>Demo</name>
<description>
    ...
</description>
<author email="myEmailAddress">
    Jeroen Claes
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />
<preference name="orientation"                value="default" />        <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
<preference name="target-device"              value="universal" />      <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
<preference name="fullscreen"                 value="true" />           <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->
<preference name="webviewbounce"              value="true" />           <!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->
<preference name="prerendered-icon"           value="true" />           <!-- ios: if icon is prerendered, iOS will not apply it's gloss to the app's icon on the user's home screen -->
<preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: external links should open in the default browser, 'true' would use the webview the app lives in -->
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle"         value="black-opaque" />   <!-- ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
<preference name="detect-data-types"          value="true" />           <!-- ios: controls whether data types (such as phone no. and dates) are automatically turned into links by the system -->
<preference name="exit-on-suspend"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: if set to true, app will terminate when home button is pressed -->
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the spinner won't appear on the splash screen during app loading -->
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->
<preference name="disable-cursor"             value="false" />          <!-- blackberry: prevents a mouse-icon/cursor from being displayed on the app -->
<preference name="android-installLocation"    value="auto" />           <!-- android: app install location. 'auto' will choose. 'internalOnly' is device memory. 'preferExternal' is SDCard. -->


<!-- Plugins -->

<!-- Core plugins -->
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm"/>

<!-- Third party plugins -->
<!-- A list of available plugins are available at https://build.phonegap.com/plugins -->

<!-- Define app icon for each platform. -->
<icon src="icon.png" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="ldpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="mdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="hdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="xhdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" />
<icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="114" height="114" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="144" height="144" />
<icon src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png"          gap:platform="webos" />
<icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png"  gap:platform="winphone" />
<icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" gap:platform="winphone"   gap:role="background" />

<!-- Define app splash screen for each platform. -->
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png"      gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png"              gap:platform="blackberry" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"         gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="1136" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"           gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"          gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg"      gap:platform="winphone" />

<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<!-- Added the following intents to support the removal of whitelist code from base cordova to a plugin -->
<!-- Whitelist configuration. Refer to https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html -->
<!--     <allow-intent href="http://*/*" /> -->
<!--     <allow-intent href="https://*/*" /> -->
<!--     <allow-intent href="tel:*" /> -->
<!--     <allow-intent href="sms:*" /> -->
<!--     <allow-intent href="mailto:*" /> -->
<!--     <allow-intent href="geo:*" /> -->
<!--     <allow-intent href="*" /> -->
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="winphone">
</platform>

</widget>
```

I've also added the following to my index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

I'm even using the following params before sending my jquery post to the server:

```
$.support.cors = true;
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
```

Each time I send an ajax request I receive a 403 error: forbidden
This is the ajax request I'm sending:

```
var sr = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>";
sr += "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" >";
    sr += "<soap:Body>";
sr += "<wsse:Username>" + username + "</wsse:Username>";
sr += "<wsse:Password>" + password + "</wsse:Password>";
sr += "<\/soap:Body>";
sr += "<\/soap:Envelope>";

$.ajax({
    headers: {  'SOAPAction': "\"Login\""
                },
    url:"https://host:port/demo/Login",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    accepts:"application/xml; text/xml; \*/\*",
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: sr,
    processData: false,
    success: function(resp){...},
    fail: function(err){...}});
```

Comment: Do you have "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" defined on the server side?

Comment: not sure, but the message doesn't even seem to get to the server. Also when posting the same message from a browser or from SOAPUI the call is successfull.

Comment: Are you loading any scripts from a CDN or other external source?

Comment: Also, "from a browser" doesn't convey enough information.  Is the browser looking at the page on the same domain that the ajax request is hitting?  If so, then it will not encounter a CORS issue but your PhoneGap application will.  Please read up on "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" and enabling it on the server side.

Comment: i just open the html page with a browser (right click, open with) while the client is connected to the same network as the mobile phone. The server is on a separate network and accessed through the internet.

Answer (score 0):

@Jeroen,
**CORS** or 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is not required. This is a common misconception with Phonegap. 'CORS' is a wevbrowser security protocol. It is not a Mobile App security protocol.

To be clear, the webview library used for Cordova/Phonega renders HTML, but it is NOT a webbrowser. The [wikipedia explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) for CORS is half-bad, but the explanation works. CORS always starts with a webbrowser that is capable of CORS. Again, CORS does NOT exist on Cordova/Phonegap.

This FAQ should also help.
[Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md) see: [#5](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#005)

Your connections issue in the `CSP`. This is also a common mistake, mostly because all the examples are poor - including those on the Cordova and Phonegap website.

**NOTE YOUR APP IS NOW INSECURE. IT IS UP TO YOU TO SECURE YOUR APP.**
Add the following to your `index.html`. Note, the star (`*`) which is missing in your file.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
         content="default-src *; 
                  style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
                  script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

You can also remove all Javascript from your `index.html`, it should have the same effect.

This *whitelist* worksheet should help with other parts.
[HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)

Make sure you also read the: [`whitelist matrix`](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/whitelist-matrix.md) and the [Whitelist CSP Examples](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/whitelist-csp-examples.md)

Best of Luck

Comment: unfortunately, this is still returning the same error as before.

Comment: Is there a way I can test this? Either that or let me look at your code.

Comment: i've also tested doing a GET on the same server and this succeeds without any issues. It's just the POST that is giving the 403 error

Comment: Well, I looked at your code. It's unusually clean - which is nice. However, it is overly complicated. This may be some tricks you are using in the Jquery. This i get from code below "// End boilerplate code." Unfortunately, I am not familiar with POST at the *xmlhttp* level. I am with GET and  PATCH, because I used them with [firebase](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/AjaxLite-Firebase). However, given that your code is working with GET, I think this is a configuration error with POST, or a server error. I lean toward the first. Sorry I can't help you more.

Comment: FWIW, you need to add to your Original Post that you got GET to work and you need POST. That will get persons more familiar with Jquery on this subject and it removes the need to review your `whitelist` filters, because if GET is working, that means you are talking to the server, and it is NOT the `whitelist` or the network. --Best of Luck